# Open model after select an Item from selection? Laravel

Tags: laravel, model, selection

I have this selection right here:

```
 {!! Form::open(['action' => 'ProductController@products', 'method' => 'post']) !!}
 {!! Form::select('product_id', $products) !!}
 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

---

$products variable:

```
$products = Products::lists('name', 'id')->toArray();
```

---

Now I have a working model. I've used the model on my other project with images.

Other Projects model I want to use:

---

Open the Model:

```
@foreach($themes as $thema)
      <a style="cursor: pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{ $thema->id }}">
            <span class="text">{{ $thema->thema }}<br></span>
      </a>
@endforeach
```

---

The Model:

```
@foreach($themes as $thema)
    <div class="modal fade" id="{{ $thema->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">

                    // not important

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                // not important

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

My problem is that I couldn't figure out how I can open the model by clicking on an item I've selected. Something like right in the time I click on an Item in the select-box, the model pops up.

or creating a button that gets the product_id and open the model if it gets klicked.

My knowledge in Javascript is to small to create this and maybe there is another way but I couldn't find one yet.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: With this approach you will end up having alot of modals in your page if your data grow in the db. Why not have one modal and populate its content with data after clicking, with an AJAX call maybe.

Comment: I'd love to do that but my skills in JS / AJAX aren't good enough to realize that.

Comment: AJAX would be the best solution in my opinion. A quick and dirty method would be to pass all the themes to a JavaScript array on loading the page, and to render one modal. When the data-toggle link is clicked to open the modal, you could update the content of the modal with JavaScript / jQuery and set it to the right theme, based on the ID of the theme in the link.

Answer (score 1):

```
  //HTML

 @foreach($variable as $fromController)
    <tr>
        <td> <a data-id="{{ $fromController->id }}"></a>{{ $fromController->name }} </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach

    <div class="modal">

    </div>



     //JAVASCRIPT (AJAX)
//Jquery required

<script>
$('a[data-id]').click(function(event) {
    var val = $(this).attr('data-id');

    $.ajax({
        url: '/getdata',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {id: val},
        success: function(data){
            $('.modal').html(data['value']).modal('show');
        }
    });


    return false;
});
</script>


//Route

Route::post('/getdata', 'ControllerName@getData');

//Controller

public function getData(Request $req){
    $get = Model::where('id', $req->input('id'))->first();
    //Assuming you have a column named "description"

    return response()->json(['value' => $get->description]);
}
```

Hope you can get idea from that. This way you have only one modal.

Comment: what will description will be? I don't have a column like that. So can I write this instead: return response()->json(['value' => $get]);

Comment: I said assuming. So description will be the name of your column whose value you want to show in the modal

Answer (score 0):

In a [MVC framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller#Components) like Laravel you shouldn't use your model to format your output. This is the work of the view.

This code should be in the view and call a method in the controller using Javascript. You can't call the model using Javascript.

Comment: I think he's refering to bootstrap Modal not Eloquent Model

Comment: Yes, Michel is right. I'm talking about the bootstrap Model :)